# pageStorageKey() is not working on ListView.builder() when I scroll FAST

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to save the state of `Listview.builder`, while I am loading new data from the network.

In other words, I am trying to do lazy loader and using `PageStorageKey` in order to save the state of the `Listview.builder` and It works, partially.

So, problem is when I scroll right **slowly**, it works and saves current state. However If I scroll **quickly**, it brings me back at the first element.

Here is the code

```
class CategorySlider extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategorySlider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 260,
      child: BlocBuilder<SliderCubit, SliderState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is SliderLoading) {
            return Center();
          } else if (state is SliderLoaded) {
            return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>( // It is how I am listening Scrolls 
              onNotification: (notification) {
                if (notification.metrics.extentAfter <= 0.0) {
                  BlocProvider.of<SliderCubit>(context).sliderLazyLoad(); // Here I am calling data from Network and switch states, while it's loading
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                key: const PageStorageKey<String>('Loaded'), //Here is PageStorageKey()
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: state.model.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListViewCenterFrame(
                    itemDistance: 25,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        // My widgets
                      ],
                    ),
                    index: index,
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const SizedBox();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts? is everything clear in question?

Comment: I solved it using `ScrollController`, common way. After long time research I found out that  `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` acts differently, despite that it is using to listen scrolls too. `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` is lazy and need some time to update current index of ListView . So instead of that use just `ScrollController` with stateful widget.